# pthread_mutex_lock and pthread_mutex_lock in another thread

Tags: c++, c, linux, multithreading, pthreads

I called a `pthread_mutex_lock(&th)` in a thread then I want to unlock the mutex in another thread `pthread_mutex_unlock(&th)`

Is it possible to do that?

Or the mutex should be unlocked in the same thread ?

Comment: Don't do that. You need to rethink your algorithm. Possibly try to use semaphores.

Comment: 'Or the mutex should be unlocked in the same thread ?' No, the mutex MUST be unlocked by the same thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be unlocked in the same thread. From the man page: "If a thread attempts to unlock a mutex that it has not locked or a mutex which is unlocked, undefined behavior results." (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/pthread_mutex_lock.html)

Answer (score 2):

I just wanted to add to Guijt's answer:
When a thread locks a mutex, it is assumed it is inside a critical section. If we allow another thread to unlock that mutex, the first thread might still be inside the critical section, resulting in problems.

I can see several solutions to your problem:

**Option 1**: Rethink your algorithm

Try to understand why you need to unlock from a different thread, and see if you can get the unlocking to be done within the locking thread. This is the best solution, as it typically produces the code that is simplest to understand, and simplest to prove it is actually doing what you believe it is doing. With multithreaded programming being so complicated, the price it is worth paying for such simplicity should be quite high.

**Option 2**: Synchronize the threads with an event

One might argue it is just a method to implement option 1 above. The idea is that when the locking thread finishes with the critical section, it does not go out to do whatever, but waits on an event. When the second thread wishes to release the lock, it instead signals the event. The first thread then releases the lock.

This procedure has the advantage that thread 2 cannot inadvertently release the lock too soon.

**Option 3**: Don't use a mutex

If neither one of the above options work for you, you most likely are not using the mutex for mutual exclusion, but for synchronizations. If such is the case, you are likely using the wrong construct.

The construct most resembling a mutex is a semaphore. In fact, for years the Linux kernel did not have a mutex, claiming that it's just a semaphore with a maximal value of 1. A semaphore, unlike a mutex, does not require that the same thread lock and release.

RTFM on sem_init and friends for how to use it.

Please be reminded that you must first model your problem, and only then choose the correct synchronization construct to use. If you do it the other way around, you are almost certain to introduce lots of bugs that are really really really difficult to find and fix.

Answer (score 0):

Whole purpose of using Mutex is achieve mutual exclusion in a critical section with ownership being tracked by the kernel. So mutex has to be unlocked in the same thread which has acquired it